# Run two promises that the same parameter

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm playing around with Rx.js and I'm looking to run two promises one that creates a directory and one that makes a http request, both take one parameter `user`. How would I chain these two things together?

```
const GITHUB_USER = 'reggi'

let repos = Rx.Observable.just(GITHUB_USER)
  .map(user => {
    return createDir(user)
  })
  .map(user => {
    return getRepos(user)
  })
```

Comment: what is your issue? Is that to reuse the `user` variable or to chain the promises? Chaining two promises is easy - just chain flatmap them. To reuse the `user` variable just pass it on to the next call. Or are you looking for an elegant way to do that?

Comment: What would happen in this program that would cause the creation of a directory or making a http request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `flatMap` operator allows you to 'flatten' an Observable of Promises (ie convert a stream of Promises that resolve something to just a stream of the resolved data):

```
const GITHUB_USER = 'reggi'

// repos$ is a stream that will resolve the user's repositories
// once the directory is created.
let repos$ = Rx.Observable.just(GITHUB_USER)
  .flatMap(user => {
    // Return a Promise that resolves the user
    return createDir(user).then(() => user);
  })
  .flatMap(user => {
    // Return a Promise that resolves the repos
    return getRepos(user)
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! In this scenario createDir doesn't return user again. :(

Comment: Updated so the createDir promise ends up resolving the user by calling `then`.

Answer (score 0):

What you *could* do is cheat a little:

```
let repos = Rx.Observable.just(GITHUB_USER)
  .map(user => {
    return createDir(user).then(res_cd => { 
      return getRepos(user);
    });
  })
  .then(res => {...})
```

It's not ideal, but it'll work.